# MVC4 on VS 2010 , using Nuget for Foundation Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Downloaded and Installed  MVC4 . Create Internet Application with default MVC4 site.I have Installed Foundation Framework by using the NuGet package that is available. It picks-up my classes from foundations css , but the in no visual changes in IE.The files has been added automatically and bundles added in my app after using NuGet.

Any one having same problem , or am I missing something. 
MVC4 looks to be different monster to MVC3 .....

Comment: Did you use the classes anywhere?

Comment: <a class="button nice">ActiveDirectory</a>

Comment: also tried <p class="label warning">Directory</p>

Comment: Fixed ... Un-Installed the NuGet Package for Foundation Framework2. Downloaded Foundation Framework 3 and did bundling manually in MVC4 and added them to my shared view.